# HTML Table wraps when converted to PDF

Tags: itext

I have a very simple table in HTML which contains 12 columns. I'm trying to convert this to PDF using iText 5.1.1 (Java).

My problem is, the table in the PDF output wraps. I mean, it displays the first row, but wraps the row at the end of the page, then without a linebreak or anything, it just displays the next row starting right after the last cell of the previous row.

How can I make iText's HtmlWorker 'nowrap' my table, namely display a single row in exatcly one row in the PDF?

BTW, I still want to cell data to be wrapped, just not the table rows:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4  
h5 c1 c2 c3  
c4 c5
```

Instead of a screenshot, `h -> header cell`, `c -> data cell` ... basically that's how the table will look like in PDF, instead of:

```
h1 h2 h3 h4 h5  
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Hi, see quazi screenshot above :)

Comment: My first guess is that iText isn't able to figure out your HTML table structure. Do you have a bunch of colspans in your table? iText requires a fixed set of columns and then every "draw" cell command is applied left to right, top to bottom. The fact that you're getting "wrapping" tells me that iText isn't able to get your column count correct. Can you post some (simplified) HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024737/html-table-wraps-when-converted-to-pdf#comment24621904_17024737) wrote in his comment above, unaligned `colspans` can and will mess with **iText** 's HTML-Worker when converting tables. I got an ill-formatted HTML template to work with and after setting the correct `colspan` values and having the correct number of cells, the problem went away.